# Lift of Fundamental groups implies the inverse image is reducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider smooth complex varieties $X$ and $Y$ such that there is a finite etale morphism $p:X\rightarrow Y$. Let $Z$ be a smooth subvariety of $Y$. We have the morphism of fundamental groups :

$$p_*:\pi_1(X)\rightarrow \pi_1(Y)\ \text{and}$$
$$i_*:\pi_1(Z)\rightarrow\pi_1(Y)\,.$$

Suppose there is a morphism $g:\pi_1(Z)\rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ such that $p_*\circ g=i_*$, then what does this say?

Does it mean that $p^{-1}(Z)$ is a reducible subvariety of $X$?

Edit - I want to assume that the degree of the finite map is $\geq 2$.

Comment: I guess there is a silly counterexample where $X = Y = Z$ and $p$ is the identity map. Maybe the question to ask to exclude examples like this is whether the homomorphism $g$ is realized by an isomorphism of $Z$ onto some connected component of $p^{-1}(Z)$.

Comment: @hunter maybe i should mention that the degree of the finite map is $\geq 2$

Comment: Just a trivial observation, but it at least seems true if you assume that $X$ is simply connected.

Comment: Can you please sketch an argument?

Comment: @gradstudent I didn't check the details but the map $i_\ast$ has trivial image since $X$ is simply connected, and so we'll get a contradiction if we show that $i_\ast$ is surjective. So, suppose that $p^{-1}(Z)$ is connected. Then, I think we can apply the general fact that a map on $\pi_1$'s is surjective if pullback of connected is connected and the fact that $X$ is the universal cover some dominates all other covers. This gives us a contradiction. This was a fleeting thought though, so there might be a trivial error.

Comment: @alex, i want the preimage to be reducible. Not necessarily disconnected.

Comment: @gradstudent But if you assume that the preimage is irreducible it is in particular connected, which gave us a contradiction. Am I being silly?

Comment: @alex, i dont understand one point. Why is the inverse image of $Z$ has to be connected for every cover isn't it? Is there anyway of proving this without assuming $X$ simply connected? The $X$ i have are not simply connected.

Comment: @gradstudent This is where I'm using the fact that $X$ is simply connected for then it dominates every other cover and so the pullback to an intermediate cover should be the image of the pullback to the universal cover--so if the latter is connected so then should be the former. I don't know right now. I'll maybe think about it more if I have some time. This was just a knee-jerk reaction to your post. Hopefully somebody with more time/knowledge will answer in the interim.

Comment: @gradstudent Did you ever make any progress on this?